# 404 Error while using Flask web app in PyInstaller executable

Tags: pyinstaller

I have a web application based on Flask, when I run it from the script `python my_script.py --web`, it works well.

However after I package it using PyInstaller with `pyinstaller my_script.spec` and run it with `.\my_script.exe --web`, everything seems to work fine according to the log and the web application is opened at a port (checked with `netstat`)

But in browser it gives "404 Not Found"

Comment: create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The app requires some part of the code in my `frontend/dist` folder. To run Flask application, we have to copy the code needed to the same path of the executable, which is copy `frontend` to `dist\my_script`